# How can i pass a html url with parameters in an url parameter

Tags: url-parameters, pdf.js

I use the pdf.js viewer to embed a PDF in an iframe. To do this, I use the:

" ?file= < path-string> " parameter. This path isn't a full path to an PDF file but a URL with own parameters. 
This own parameters were removed on execution.

How can I pass a URL with parameters in the parameter "file"?
Or: Is it another way to run the viewer with an URL?

Answer (score 1):

As written here, https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#file, you have to encode your URL with encodeURIComponent();