# How to display PDF using URL when implementing pdf.js using iframe in React

Tags: reactjs, pdf.js

I am following this website https://www.pdftron.com/blog/react/how-to-build-a-react-pdf-viewer/ to implement pdf.js using iframe in React

However, in this tutorial, the pdf is a local file in public folder.

```
   <PDFViewer backend={WebviewerBackend} src='/myPDF.pdf' />
```

How do I use a third party url as the src? For example, I want to display pdf in this url https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.3531.pdf

Comment: Just follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963992/how-can-i-pass-a-html-url-with-parameters-in-an-url-parameter